# How long does it take for BBOS 10 app to get approved by Blackberry App World?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-world

I already search around the forum. People said that it takes almost 2 weeks, but all these topics are quite old and it is for the old Blackberry OS (5,6,7).

So just wonder how long it takes for BBOS 10 apps?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Blackberry app approval process

Comment: Hi Mike, just ask this question because I am curious. I know that many people may have the same question. To be honest, everyone feel excited when they finished their app and are waiting to be published. Cheers,

Comment: It took my friend 5 days, it took me 3 weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. Sometimes, it gets approved in a couple of days, sometimes, in a couple of weeks. Depends mainly on the number of applications they have to evaluate at that time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am just curious cause last time I registered for the vendor account and it took me nearly 4 months to receive a denied email. I had to email them again and provided lots of identifying evidences.